# Backdrop-filter grayscale does not work for Mozilla

Tags: css, firefox

backdrop-filter: grayscale(1); works perfectly for chrome but not for firefox. Any idea how I could tackle this or find a workaround? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I hope the below link would help you. You should add a prefix "-webkit-" like

eg:

```
> `-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);  
 backdrop-filter: blur(10px);`
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter

Comment: Hello and thanks for the response. I've already tried that and it did not work.

Comment: Is there any warning on it? in dev tools CSS?

Comment: Yes, invalid property name, but as you can see in the link you sent, it seems to be supported in Mozilla.

Answer (score 1):

you will have to use `filter: grayscale(100%);`

```css
.bg {
  background: url(https://placeimg.com/200/200/any);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <h1>Title here</h1>
  <p>Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Fusce a quam. Sed a libero. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer. The problem is that I want the filter to be applied to the background and not on the element(It is a pop up).

Comment: Doesn't `backdrop-filter: grayscale(1);` work?

Answer (score 1):

[Mozzila browser support for Backdrop Fillter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter#Browser_compatibility) says

> From version 70: this feature is behind the layout.css.backdrop-filter.enabled preference (needs to be set to true) and the gfx.webrender.all preference (needs to be set to true). To change preferences in Firefox, visit about:config.

So to enable backdrop-filter on mozilla go to "about:config" (in the address bar) and set to **true** both **layout.css.backdrop-filter.enabled** and **gfx.webrender.all**.

Hope this helps, cheers!